# Coffeescript compilation fails for no apparent reason

Tags: coffeescript

When I try to compile this script (`first.coffe`):

```
some_object = 
  property_a : 123
  property_b : "hello"
```

I get following error:

```
In first.coffee, Parse error on line 2: Unexpected 'INDENT'
```

but when I use "try coffeescript" functionality of coffeescript [website](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#top), everything seems to work fine, because output is exactly this:

```
var some_object;

some_object = {
  property_a: 123,
  property_b: "hello"
};
```

What am I doing wrong? I work on Ubuntu, so coffescript was installed from repositories.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? I think [only Ubuntu 11.10 has an up-to-date CoffeeScript](http://oylenshpeegul.typepad.com/blog/2011/10/coffeescript-in-ubuntu-1110.html). Your example works for me.

Comment: Done. Have fun with CoffeeScript...I think it's a blast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ubuntu 11.10 has an up-to-date CoffeeScript package.](http://oylenshpeegul.typepad.com/blog/2011/10/coffeescript-in-ubuntu-1110.html) Older versions of Ubuntu may have a CoffeeScript package that is too old. If you are using an Ubuntu older than 11.10, uninstall that package and install a newer CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 2):

It might have something to do with your text editor. I know I've had trouble before with indent settings and line endings. Try opening it up in a different editor if you are using VIM.

Comment: I tried both VIM and gedit with tabs or spaces and problem remained